# receive 500 http error when make request from vuex store. in vue js

Tags: vue.js, http, vuex, http-status-code-500

to add data to the server by axios POST method, I receive 500 HTTP error.

it occurs when the request is made from vuex store.

when the request is form component there isn't any problem.

```js
export
default {
  name: 'addCategoury',

  data: () => ({
    name: '',
    src: '',
    description: '',
  }),
  methods: {


    async AddCat() {
      const newCategory = {
        categoryName: this.name,
        description: this.description,
        imageUrl: this.src,
      }
      let result = await this.$store.dispatch('AddCategory', newCategory)
      if (result.data) {
        alert('shode');
      } else {
        alert('result failed')
      }


    }

  }
}
////////////////////in store js////////////////////
import Vue from 'vue'
import Vuex from 'vuex'
import api from '../services/API'


Vue.use(Vuex)

export default new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    categories: []
  },
  getters: {
  },
  mutations: {
    get_category(state, cat) {

    }
  },  


  actions: {
  
    async AddCategory(newCategory) {

      try {
        let result = await api().post('/category/create',newCategory);
        console.log(result)
        if (result.data) {
          alert('ok')
          return result
        }
      } catch (error){
        return error
      }

    }
  },
 
})
////////////////////in API js////////////////////
import axios from 'axios'

export default () => {
    return axios.create({
        baseURL: 'https://limitless-lake-55070.herokuapp.com'
       

    })
}
```

```html
<template>
  <v-container class="align-text-center">

    <v-form class="form">
      <v-container>
        <v-row>
          <v-col cols="7">
            <v-text-field outlined v-model="name" label="name" required>
            </v-text-field>
          </v-col>

          <v-col cols="7">
            <v-text-field outlined v-model="src" label="image Source" required>
            </v-text-field>
          </v-col>

          <v-col cols="7">
            <v-text-field outlined v-model="description" label="description"></v-text-field>
          </v-col>
          <v-col cols="12">
            <v-btn @click="AddCat">
              ADD
            </v-btn>
          </v-col>
        </v-row>
      </v-container>
    </v-form>

  </v-container>
</template>
```

to add data to the server by axios POST method, I receive 500 HTTP error.

it occurs when the request is made from vuex store.

when the request is form component there isn't any problem.

// in the component

```js
methods:{
async AddCat() {
      const newCategory = {
        categoryName: this.name,
        description: this.description,
        imageUrl: this.src,
      }

      let result = await this.$store.dispatch('AddCategory', newCategory)

      if(result.data){
        alert('dode');
      } else {
        alert('result failed')
      }} }
```

// in the store.js

```js
    import api from '../services/API'
    actions: {
      
        async AddCategory(newCategory) {
    
          try {
            let result = await api().post('/category/create',newCategory);
            console.log(result)
            if (result.data) {
              alert('ok')
              return result
            }
          } catch (error){
            return error
          }
    
    
        }
      },
```

// API

```js
    import axios from 'axios'

    export default () => {
      return axios.create({
        baseURL: 'https://limitless-lake-55070.herokuapp.com'     
      })
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

So I see you're using $store.dispatch, I am assuming you want to use vue actions. I will explain my code after the solution below:

Your component file looks fine to me, please make sure to add the import file too. It plays a big role in your files too, we won't be able to debug without that.

api.js // would be your file where you're setting the default URL for Axios

```
import axios from "axios";

export default () => {
  return axios.create({
    baseURL: "https://limitless-lake-55070.herokuapp.com"
  });
};
```

store.js // Actions object is missing from your question

```
import api from "../plugins/api";

export const actions = {
 async AddCategory(newCat) {

    try {
      let res = await api().post('/category/create',newCat)
      let result = res.status;
      if (result == 200 || result == 201) {
        
        alert('ok')

      }
    } catch(error) {
     console.log('dd')

     }

  },
}
```

Comment: thank you. I added  files but I couldnt upload   js file separately